# Yii2 DAC + PostgreSQL JSONB

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Исходные данные:

SQL выборка по колонке типа JSONB

```
SELECT * FROM project where guest_users ?| array['abcd'];
```

Обращаться к БД пробовал тремя способами:

**1) через DAC**

```
$user_name = 'abcd';
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$res = $db->createCommand("select * 
   from project 
   where guest_users ?| array['".$user_name."']")
  ->queryOne();
```

**2) через Query**

```
   $user_name = 'abcd';
   $res = (new Query())->select(*)
     ->from(Project::tableName())
     ->where([
        "?|",
        "guest_users", 
        new Expression("array['".$user_name."']")
      ])
      ->one();
```

**3) через Query c Expression**

```
$user_name = 'abcd';

$res = (new Query())->select(*)
   ->from(Project::tableName())
   ->where([
      new Expression("?|"),
      "guest_users",
      new Expression("array['".$user_name."']")
   ])
   ->one();
```

Вне зависимости от формы обращения штатный yii\db\Exception не пропускает запрос на исполнение т.к. знак вопроса подменяется знаком доллара (? на $), хотя возвращает рабочий SQL

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
>   LINE 1: ...ct" FROM "project" WHERE "guest_users" $1|
>   array[... ^ The SQL being executed was: SELECT
>   * FROM "project" WHERE "guest_users" ?| array['abcd']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема уходит в API `prepared statements` в `PDO`, который парсит строку запроса в поиске параметров неименованных `?` и успешно такой находит там где не надо. Есть и [родственный баг](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71885) в трекере.

То есть корень проблемы на два уровня глубже и иллюстрируется вот так:

```
$pdo = new pdo('pgsql:', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    ]);

$s = $pdo->prepare("select '{}'::jsonb ?| array['foo']");
$s->execute();
```

Баг именно в PHP, прямыми способами не чинится. Но postgresql штука весьма гибкая и могу предложить пару способов обхода проблемы со стороны базы:

### Узнать, что любой оператор - это функция

Оператору `?|` между `JSONB` и `text[]` [соответствует функция](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/include/catalog/pg_operator.dat#L3312) `jsonb_exists_any`. Её можно вызывать напрямую:

```
where jsonb_exists_any(guest_users, array[...])
```

### Сделать хранимку и вызывать вместо оператора её

```
CREATE FUNCTION jsonb_keys_exists(JSONB,TEXT[]) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE AS $f$
  SELECT $1 ?| $2
$f$;
```

Тогда получится

```
where jsonb_keys_exists(guest_users, array[...])
```

### Определить свои собственные операторы

```
CREATE OPERATOR ~@| (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any);
```

И использовать этот оператор:

```
where guest_users ~@| array[...]
```